# Limit and get flat list in java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a object like this

```
public class Keyword
{
  private int id;
  private DateTime creationDate
  private int subjectId
  ...
}
```

So now i have the data list like bellow

**KeywordList** = [{1,'2018-10-20',10},{1,'2018-10-21',10},{1,'2018-10-22',10},{1,'2018-10-23',20},{1,'2018-10-24',20}{1,'2018-10-25',20},{1,'2018-10-26',30},{1,'2018-10-27',30},{1,'2018-10-28',40}]

I wanted to limit this list for subject id

**Ex: If i provide limit as 2 it should only include latest 2 records for each subject id by sorting by creationDate and return the result as list too.**

**resultList** = KeywordList = [{1,'2018-10-21',10},{1,'2018-10-22',10},{1,'2018-10-24',20},{1,'2018-10-25',20},{1,'2018-10-26',30},{1,'2018-10-27',30},{1,'2018-10-28',40}]

how we can achive this kind of thing in Java 8
I have achived it in this kind of way.But i have a doubt in this code peformance wise.

```
dataList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Keyword::getSubjectId,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                myList-> myList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Keyword::getCreationDate).reversed()).limit(limit)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
        .values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I can assume *by writing some java-8 code*

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can suppose that `DateTime` is `org.joda.time.DateTime`...probably

Comment: yes org.joda.time.DateTime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could do it in two steps I guess(assuming `DateTime` is comparable):

```
    yourInitialList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Keyword::getSubjectId));

    List<Keyword> result = map.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream()
                          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Keyword::getCreationDate))
                          .limit(2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is doable in a single step too with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` I guess, but not sure on how readable it would be.

Comment: Looks like this answeris  clear than my effort.Since my code also give me the result but hard to understand.What do you think Eugene ?

Comment: @Prabhath yeah, saw that, thing is you are collecting to a `List`, only to stream it via `flatMap` after that. also if you format your code it becomes way more clear

Comment: Yes but I want to sorted by latest date.So i need to revers it and limit.Is that the way @Eugene

Comment: @Prabhath you are asking me here? Sorry I don't understand you and yes, you could simply add `reversed` to the comparator if needed

Comment: @Prabhath care to provide an example of what you actually mean?

Comment: @Eugin.look like it is somthing with my code.This code works nicely.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Comparator<Keyword> COMPARE_BY_CREATION_DATE_DESC = (k1, k2) -> k2.getCreationDate().compareTo(k1.getCreationDate());

private static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> limitingList(int limit) {
    return Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
            (l, e) -> {
                if (l.size() < limit)
                    l.add(e);
            },
            (l1, l2) -> {
                l1.addAll(l2.subList(0, Math.min(l2.size(), Math.max(0, limit - l1.size()))));
                return l1;
            }
    );
}

public static <R> Map<R, List<Keyword>> retrieveLast(List<Keyword> keywords, Function<Keyword, ? extends R> classifier, int limit) {
    return keywords.stream()
                   .sorted(COMPARE_BY_CREATION_DATE_DESC)
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, limitingList(limit)));
}
```

And the client's code:

```
List<Keyword> keywords = Collections.emptyList();
Map<Integer, List<Keyword>> map = retrieveLast(keywords, Keyword::getSubjectId, 2);
```

Comment: talking about the verbosity as we had a few days ago... not entirely sure a custom collector for this is something *I* (emphases on **I**) would like here... also you don't have to creat that `COMPARE_BY_CREATION_DATE_DESC`, you could do it via `Comparator.comparing... `